# How to schedule a campaign in eloqua by api?

Tags: eloqua

Am working in Eloqua 10. I am creating a dotnet application to create campaign by using eloqua rest api.

I am able to create campaign and activate a campaign.

But how can I schedule a campaign that should be activated on a specific date?

Is there any way to achieve the same using eloqua api?

Comment: Have you tried the activate endpoint? Check my answer below: /assets/campaign/active/{id}?scheduledFor={scheduledFor}

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use mozilla-f12-network and there are all HTTP requests which are made. That means, if you define the specific activation date in eloqua and click save it will run HTTP request which will be tracked in the Mozilla Network.

Since the REST api are just HTTP requests you can make one according to that.

I am very sure it works, I did it the same way, just make it right.

Answer (score -1):

Try running the following:

`POST /assets/campaign/active/{id}?scheduledFor={scheduledFor}&runAsUserId={runAsUserId}&activateNow={activateNow}`

If you are using the Eloqua Rest API, here is the doc for the campaign endpoint: http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAB/index.html#Developers/RESTAPI/2.0%20Endpoints/Campaigns/put-assets-campaign.htm